# Pagination for Crossslide?

Tags: html, css, jquery

I need to implement pagination for crossslide slideshow
can anyone tell me how to implement pagination in [crossslide slideshow](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/)?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: How do you imagine "pagination" for this type of slideshow?

Comment: I woould prefer the way the bullets are moving for each image in this site...http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Comment: Hm. Why not use NivoSlider then?

Comment: but..!! i guess there is no pan and zoom like that of crossslide.. i need the pan and zoom  animation along with pagination...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following could be a possible solution for you, though it is not perfect.

For example, you have the config as:

```
$test3.crossSlide({
            fade: 1
        }, [
            { // #1
                src:  'sand-castle.jpg',
                alt:  'Sand Castle',
                from: '100% 80% 1x',
                to:   '100% 0% 1.7x',
                time: 3
            },
            { // #2
                src:  'flip-flops.jpg',
                alt:  'Flip Flops',
                from: '100% 80% 1.5x',
                to:   '80% 0% 1.1x',
                time: 2
            }
        ]
    );
```

If the user wants to see the second image, you can just re-order the configuration and
call the crossSlide() again. The second image will show immediately.

```
$test3.crossSlide({
        fade: 1
    }, [
        { // #2
            src:  'flip-flops.jpg',
            alt:  'Flip Flops',
            from: '100% 80% 1.5x',
            to:   '80% 0% 1.1x',
            time: 2
        }, {
            //#1
            src:  'sand-castle.jpg',
            alt:  'Sand Castle',
            from: '100% 80% 1x',
            to:   '100% 0% 1.7x',
            time: 3
        }
    ]
);
```

For instance, the pagination code can be something like:

```
<a class='change_img' data-img='1' style='cursor: pointer'>#1</a>
<a class='change_img' data-img='2' style='cursor: pointer'>#2</a>
...
<a class='change_img' data-img='5' style='cursor: pointer'>#5</a>

$('.change_img').live('click', function(){
    var images = [/* your configuration */]; 
    var idx = parseInt($(this).attr('data-img'));
    var tmp = images.splice(0, idx-1);
    images = images.concat(tmp);
    $('#your_placeholder').crossSlide({fade:1}, images);
});
```

Comment: hai Liangliang Zheng, thanks for your response but i need a pagination that changes on click ...the answer u gave can be done only with codes. i would like to changes the images on click...

Comment: I assume you will have some buttons, clicking which will trigger some function to change to that image. isn't it?

Comment: yes... exactly... i have created bullets and when clicked on each bullets i need the image to change correspondingly!!

Comment: I have tested the code. Should work. Did you change the code according to your own page? e.g., 'your_placeholder' should be the id of your place holder